# What is the different between /[^\n\S]*:(?!:)/ and /[^\n\S]*:/ in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was reading the source code of lex of coffeescript, and I got below regex for IDENTIFIER

`IDENTIFIER = /^([$A-Za-z_\x7f-\uffff][$\w\x7f-\uffff]*)([^\n\S]*:(?!:))?/;`

Just not sure why (?!:) is required though I know it is a  non-capturing negative lookahead group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires that the match not be followed by a second `:`. Without it, the match *could* be followed by a second `:`. So with that negative lookahead, given the input `foo::`, only `foo` matches; *without* it there, given the input `foo::`, `foo:` (with the colon) matches. You can play with it over on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xZ7wR0/1).